# Une traduction pour « les grands gens »

Tags: traduction, néerlandais, enfants

Je veux tirer au clair comment on dit en français *de grote mensen*, ce qui veut dire 
*les grands gens*. J’essaie ci-dessous d’expliquer quand on utilise cette combinaison de mots et qu’est-ce qu’elle veut dire.

C’est un mot qu’on utilise pour éviter l’emploi de « les gens adultes » quand on parle avec un jeune enfant, car beaucoup de petits ne connaissent pas ce mot. Quand ils ont sept ou huit ans, ils apprennent ce mot, et la tournure devient donc inutile. À partir de cet âge, aucun enfant ne l'utilise encore car elle est un peu enfantine.

Un père peut dire à son jeune fils qu’il doit faire « des choses de grands gens », quand il va travailler. Il peut le priver de choses nuisibles, comme le vin, en disant que c’est seulement pour « les grands gens ». Il peut lui parler de sa « fête d’anniversaire pour des grands gens », c’est ce qu’on fête avec la famille élargie (je cherche à exprimer ce qui inclut les oncles, tantes, grand-mères, pas un seul ménage.)

Les enfants eux-mêmes utilisent ce mot dans un cadre plus étendu : Tous les gens qui sont grands en hauteur, qui semblent agir librement, et qui prennent soin d’eux-mêmes peuvent être appelés des « grands gens ». Les ados qui ont quinze ans ou plus font souvent partie de cet ensemble.

Encore un fait qui ne peut pas manquer : La tournure est usitée au pluriel. Je pense que je n’ai jamais entendu dire « un grand homme », ou quelque chose de semblable.

Est-ce qu’il y a un mot ou un enchainement de mots qui joue un pareil rôle en français ?

Comment: @Mina. Je vous remercie pour avoir amélioré le français de cette question ! Quant à « la famille élargie », je pense à remplacer ce morceau par quelque chose de mieux, pour effacer ce qui la suit. Qu’en pensez-vous ?

Comment: Je vous avoue avoir trouvé votre texte original tellement _mignon/touchant_: Le détail avec lequel vous avez tenté de decrire l'expression que vous rechercher me laisse penser qu'il pourrait s'agir de vos propres enfants ou petits enfants.

Comment: Quant à « la famille élargie »; il s'agit là d'une expression tout à fait usitée, comme le montre [cet outil](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=famille+%C3%A9largie&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfamille%20%C3%A9largie%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: C'est étrange de ne pas utiliser un mot avec les enfants sous prétexte qu'ils ne le connaissent pas. Je peux comprendre pour _varlope_, mais _adulte_, c'est pas tellement plus compliqué que _poussette_ et c'est au moins aussi courant dans l'environnement immédiat de l'enfant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Les grandes personnes

correspondent exactement aux définitions de la question.

L'expression s'emploie souvent au pluriel lorsque l'on parle des adultes en général.

L'usage au singulier est parfois ambigu si l'on parle d'un adulte en particulier : *c'est une grande personne* peut être employé par dérision pour *c'est un grand personnage*.

Pour un enfant une *grande personne* est un adulte.

Answer (score 3):

En français, on emploie une construction similaire : on parle de « grande personne », qui s’utilise tant au singulier qu’au pluriel.

[Dans le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/personne) ; [dans le Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/personne).

Answer (score 2):

L'expression commune la plus proche que l'on utilise en français me semble être tout simplement *les grands*.

- Le vin est seulement pour les grands, les enfants boivent du jus de raisin.
- Tu ne peux pas rester avec les grands, il est l'heure d'aller dormir.

L'expression reste cependant plus ambiguë qu'en Néerlandais me semble-t-il. On pourrait par exemple également appeler *les grands* un groupe d'enfants plus vieux.

Comment: *Les grands* représente un groupe plus étendu que *les grandes personnes* : les grandes personnes regroupent les adultes, les *grands* y ajoute (et insiste surtout) sur les adolescents et les jeunes plus âgés que l'enfant à qui l'on parle. Ils peuvent avoir le droit de boire du vin, et souvent les *grands* pour un enfant sont ses ainés, alors que ses parents sont des grandes personnes